# Store multiple xmldocument into an array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, xmldocument

I've more than two XML Document (generated through for loop, based on certain criteria) and want to store them in an array (if possible).

For example:
XmlDocument[] xmlDoc = {"xmlDoc1", "xmlDoc2"};

Is it possible to do so? If not, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your for loop dynamically generating them?

Populate a `List`, then convert that to an array.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;


// ....
List<XmlDocument> l = new List<XmlDocument>();

for(var i = 0; i < loopSize; ++i)
{
     XmlDocument doc = GenerateTheDocument(i);
     l.Add(doc);
}
XmlDocument[] asArray = l.ToArray();
```

Do you actually need it in array format? You could just use the `List` from then on.

Comment: Hi @Andrew Shepherd, the xmldocument is dynamically generated through the loop. I want to keep them as xmldocument to the end.